# Definition Query with GETDATE()

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, sql-server, definition-query

The expression FieldData1 <= GETDATE () AND FieldData2 >= GETDATE () works well, but if FieldData1 = FieldData2 does not work.
ArcGIS 10.3.1 Desktop and SQL Server 2008.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The odds of the two fields being eqivalent at the same moment of GETDATE execution seem slim. It's possible that two different vales are generated by the functions, but this seems more like a database question than a GIS one.